# Fetching PostgreSQL's nextval() from laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I'm creating a crud that makes use of wizard in Laravel. I'm wondering how I could fetch the nextval() of a certain table so I can store it as a session.

Currently, I'm doing it like this from my controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    // get all the reports
    $reports = Reports::all();
    $query = "select nextval('app_reports_mgmt.reports_rid_seq')";
    $next_rid = Reports::raw($query)->get();
    Session::put('next_rid', $next_rid);

    // load the view and pass the reports
    return View::make('templates.reports')
        ->with('reports', $reports);
}
```

but everytime I print out next_rid, it actually stored all data in the table.
It's a long result but here is a snippet of the output:

[{"rid":4,"name":"Test validation table test","encryption":"test","internal_external":"External","client":"Account 1","isdateappended":"No","savewithmacro":"xlsx","deleteconnections":"True","nameofemailbodysheet":"1","validationtables":"5","validationchecks":"","customemailtext":"3","report_status":"WIP","custom_email_subject":"2","report_pc":"ccrep-eu-rbox02","pc_user":"reporting-eu","custom_attachment_name".......

I've skimmed through laracasts and a couple more websites, but there doesn't seem to be any Laravel function for getting the nextval of a table.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value()` function.

```
public function index()
{
    // get all the reports
    $reports = Reports::all();
    $query = "nextval('app_reports_mgmt.reports_rid_seq') as nxt";
    $next_rid = Reports::selectRaw($query)->value('nxt');
    Session::put('next_rid', $next_rid);

    // load the view and pass the reports
    return View::make('templates.reports')
        ->with('reports', $reports);
}
```